# Implementing a Red Black Tree with Tnil Sentinal

Tags: c++, class, red-black-tree

I am trying to implement a Red-Black try that has a sentinel Tnil, that has the color Black with an arbitrary number. I have declared the following definitions in my header files.

**RBTree.h**

```
#ifndef RBTREE_H
#define RBTREE_H
#include "RBNode.h"



class RBTree{
private:

    static RBNode* Tnil;

    RBNode* Maximum();
    RBNode* Minimum(RBNode*);
    RBNode* Successor(RBNode*);

    void RBLeftRotate(RBNode*, RBNode*);
    void RBRightRotate(RBNode*, RBNode*);
    void RBInsertFixUp(RBNode* T, RBNode* z);
    void RBDeleteFixUp(RBNode* T, RBNode* z);

    RBNode* createNode();

public:
    friend class RBNode;
    RBNode* root;
    RBTree();
    ~RBTree();
    void RBInOrder(RBNode* node);
    void RBPreOrder(RBNode* node);
    void RBPostOrder(RBNode* node);
    void RBInsert(RBNode* T, RBNode* z);
    RBNode* RBDelete(RBNode* T, RBNode* z);
    RBNode* RBSearch(int searchValue);

};

#endif
```

**RBNode.h**

```
#ifndef RBNODE_H
#define RBNODE_H



class RBNode{
private:
    int nodeValue;
    char color;
    RBNode* left;
    RBNode* right;
    RBNode* parent;

public:
    friend class RBTree;
    RBNode();
    void printNode(RBNode*);
};

#endif
```

I am having trouble creating the Tnil sentinal with the color black and a value of -999. However when I compile this program I get an error in my cpp files (specifically the constructor of `RBNode`) when trying to set the values of Tnil.

The error I get:

```
RBNode.cpp:9:2: error: ‘Tnil’ was not declared in this scope
  Tnil->color = 'B';
  ^
```

Here is the implementation of the `RBNode.cpp`:

```
#include "RBNode.h"
#include "RBTree.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

RBNode::RBNode(){

    Tnil->color = 'B';
    Tnil->nodeValue = -999;
    Tnil->left = NULL;
    Tnil->right = NULL;
    Tnil->parent = NULL;
}

void RBNode::printNode(RBNode* node){
    cout << node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you have to assign values to static variables in the header, with full qualification. So in your header, after your declaration, add `static RBNode RBTree::Tnil = 'B';` maybe? I'm far from an expert though...

Comment: If it's `RBTree::Tnil` you want to access in `RBNode` constructor, then say so. It's strange though that every node re-initializes the same global variable over and over.

Comment: Next time post a [mcve].  You don't need all of this code to [see the error](https://www.ideone.com/BIjXBc)